# Add 700 each day in php

Tags: php

I want to add 700 to 7700 everyday but i want it to start adding the amount on a certain day for example

I want it to start on 
03/12/2016 so on this day the amount would be 7700
next day should be 8400 than next day 9100 and so on. Im having trouble coming up with a solution. This is what i have right now

```
<?php
 $now = time();
 $your_date = strtotime("2016-03-12"); //Starting date
 $datediff = floor(($now - $your_date)/(60*60*24)*700);

 echo $datediff;
 ?>
```

I found a way to do this i added this line

```
     $datediff = ($datediff * 700) + 7700;
```

Comment: Question is something? code doing something. totally confusing.

Comment: @youngkid, according to you what should be the amount for today's date?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $startDate = "2016-03-12"; //Y-m-d
    $startAmount = 7700;
    $incrAmount = 700;
    $date1 = new DateTime($startDate);
    $date2 = new DateTime("today");
    $diff = $date2->diff($date1);
    $todaysAmount = $startAmount+($incrAmount*($diff->d+1));   //+1 for start day >> 7700+(700*7)
    echo $todaysAmount; //prints 12600
?>
```

Logics mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Function that calculates custom period value:

```
<?php

$startDay = '2016-03-16';
$startValue = 7000;
$dayValue = 700;

function periodValue($startDay, $startValue, $dayValue) {
    return function($endDay) use ($startDay, $startValue, $dayValue) {
        return (
            date_diff(
                date_create($endDay),
                date_create($startDay)
            )->days) * $dayValue + $dayValue + $startValue;
    };
};


$periodValue = periodValue($startDay, $startValue, $dayValue);

$v0 = $periodValue($startDay); // 7700
$v1 = $periodValue('2016-03-17'); // 8400
$v2 = $periodValue('2016-03-18'); // 9100
```

You can easily use invert property of DateInterval class to make these calculation relative to start day in both directions.